# How to find newest file with .MP3 extension in directory?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to find the ***most recently modified*** (from here on out 'newest') file of a specific type in Python.  I can currently get the newest, but it doesn't matter what type.  I would like to only get the newest MP3 file.

Currently I have:

```
import os
  
newest = max(os.listdir('.'), key = os.path.getctime)
print newest
```

Is there a way to modify this to only give me only the newest MP3 file?

Comment: @enginefree: It's a module in the standard library that comes with Python. You just need to write `import os`, and then you can call [all of the useful functions in the module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html).

Comment: @abarnert I know what the `os` module is. I swear I did not comment that. There must be two sessions open two my account or something.

Comment: import line added to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use [glob.glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob#glob.glob):

```
import os
import glob
newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]3'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: Great solution. But the OP asked for `.MP3`, so I you want `glob('*.MP3')` to directly answer the question, although a case-insensitive is probably what he _really_ wants.

Comment: @abarnert, Thank you for comment. I updated the code to `MP3`. BTW, `iglob` is not case-insensitive version of `glob`.

Comment: There is no case-insensitive version of `glob`; you have to use `fnmatch` manually (at which point the source linked from the `glob` docs serves as great example code).

Comment: … Or do it explicitly, as you just did. :)

Comment: This is perfect, and your case insensitive assumption is correct.

Comment: @falsetru Wouldn't you want to use getmtime? getctime gets the creation time (at least on Windows), whereas getmtime returns the modified time.  So if you want the, "most recently modified" file, as asked by OP, he should have been corrected to use getmtime.

Comment: @leetNightshade, `getctime` came from OP's code. How about notify @Butters instead of me?

Comment: @falsetru Because you're the one with the "correct" answer. :p

Comment: iglob for those that aren't familiar is ITERATOR glob it returns the unprocessed iterator that glob would compact into a list.

Comment: Very useful line which works. Just one question: how could I change this to work in a different directory than the current one? I've tried to change the string to "directory+'/*.extension'", where directory is a string containing the directory and "extension" is "mp3" in this case. However, I get a "max() arg is an empty sequence" error.

Comment: @khpeek, Try `max(glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, '*.extension')), key=os.path.getctime)`: `directory` should point to the directory that is accesible (relative/absolute).

Comment: This is a very good answer for Python 2.6+. If you're still in the stone-age (like me) and using Python 2.4, this is not your solution.

Comment: @themanatuf, You can use decorate-sort-undecorate if the function does not support `key` parameter: `max([(os.path.getctime(f), f) for f in glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]3')])[1]`

Comment: Has anybody noticed problems with this solution? For some uses, I'll get the incorrect file returned. i.e. not the most recently modified... Any ideas?

Comment: @rockymonkey555, If you want to get recently **modified** file, use `getmtime` instead of `getctime`.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you have imported os and defined your path, this will work:

```
dated_files = [(os.path.getmtime(fn), os.path.basename(fn)) 
               for fn in os.listdir(path) if fn.lower().endswith('.mp3')]
dated_files.sort()
dated_files.reverse()
newest = dated_files[0][1]
print(newest)
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this guy a try:

```
import os
print max([f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.lower().endswith('.mp3')], key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: Using string methods instead of path methods on paths is a good way to run into edge-case bugs. But unless you have a good reason to do so, why even try to duplicate the batteries (`glob` and `fnmatch`) in the stdlib?

Comment: Because of 300 runs my code runs `18% faster` than falsetru's up there

Comment: And you think that time is ever going to matter in any real program? If you really care about performance, you'll shave 60-95% off by using lower-level APIs that get you the stats of each file as you scan the directory instead of calling stat on each one.

Comment: Meanwhile, besides being much more verbose and running past 80 characters, your code is also less robust—try the same code with any path other than `.` and his still works, yours does not. Micro-optimization is rarely the first thing you should worry about, especially in Python.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I wanted to contribute my answer which I had produced before I saw the other one, and the only redeeming quality I saw in it was the runtime. If you truly think my answer to be such a horridly shameful piece of code, would you prefer I delete it?

Comment: If I'd thought it was a "horridly shameful piece of code" and should be removed as an answer, I would have downvoted it instead of just commenting.

Answer (score 0):

For learning purposes here my code, basically the same as from @Kevin Vincent though not as compact, but better to read and understand:

```
import datetime
import glob
import os

mp3Dir = "C:/mp3Dir/"
filesInmp3dir = os.listdir(mp3Dir)

datedFiles = []
for currentFile in filesInmp3dir:
    if currentFile.lower().endswith('.mp3'):
        currentFileCreationDateInSeconds = os.path.getmtime(mp3Dir + "/" + currentFile)
        currentFileCreationDateDateObject = datetime.date.fromtimestamp(currentFileCreationDateInSeconds)
        datedFiles.append([currentFileCreationDateDateObject, currentFile])
        datedFiles.sort();
        datedFiles.reverse();

print datedFiles
latest = datedFiles[0][1]
print "Latest file is: " + latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more object-oriented version of @falsetru's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279182/355230) that uses the `pathlib` module. Another difference is, unlike his, it finds the most recently *modified* (not created) file.

Use `Path.glob()`:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

newest = max(Path('.').glob('*.[Mm][Pp]3'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".mp3"):
        print "",file
        newest = max(file , key = os.path.getctime)
        print "Recently modified Docs",newest
```