# Python get most recent file in a directory with certain extension

Tags: python, file, file-io

I'm trying to use the newest file in the 'upload' directory with '.log' extension to be processed by Python. I use a `Ubuntu` web server and file upload is done by a html script. The uploaded file is processed by a Python script and results are written to a `MySQL` database. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279063/python-find-newest-file-with-mp3-extension-in-directory) answer for my code.

```
import glob
newest = max(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)
print newest
f = open(newest,'r')
```

But this is not getting the newest file in the directory, instead it gets the oldest one. Why?

Comment: try `min` instead of `max` - the logical *reverse*?

Comment: This gives me the newest file when I run it from the python interactive console.

Comment: Thinking about it, you might want `os.path.getmtime` - creation times and modification times are different though... so err... not sure

Comment: @Jon Clements: Wow..:) Problem was with min,max...changed it to min and it worked..Thanks Very Much.

Comment: @Jon Clements: Could you please put this as an answer?So I can Accept it.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage okay, posted it... think there's an XY problem going on here, but if it helps you, and closes off this question, fine by me :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that the logical inverse of `max` is `min`:

```
newest = max(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

For your purposes should be:

```
newest = min(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: Newcomers looking for a way to identify the latest file need to beware because the max getctime should be the latest date, thus newest.  I find max gives the newest file on linux on AMD64 and raspberry pi.  Wonder what was going on here.

Comment: @Paul indeed... I remember when I answered this thinking the OPs approach was correct and suggest `min` over `max` was really a suggestion to see if they wanted the oldest (or just to see if the opposite was what they really wanted)...

Comment: @JonClements Hi I am doing something similar, grabbing a certain file format, where it must be the latest and within a directory. Was wondering if there are any ways for this to be done just using `os` modules without using `glob`?

Comment: @Yan I suppose you could look at using `os.listdir()`, but then you'd have to do pattern matching yourself..

Comment: it seems that each of the results is good for specific OS.might be a good idea to warn people about it. your answer got me spending a lot of time figure out what i was doing wrong just to realize that the first option did worked for me.

Comment: since `ctime` seems to be defined differently for Windows and Unix, would `mtime` be more platform independent? `newest = max(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getmtime)` seems to be working well for me.

Answer (score 1):

In many newer programs, it is preferred to use pathlib for this very common task:

```
from pathlib import Path

XLSX_DIR = Path('../../somedir/')
XLSX_PATTERN = r'someprefix*.xlsx'

latest_file = max(XLSX_DIR.glob(XLSX_PATTERN), key=lambda f: f.stat().st_ctime)
```