# Second newest file

Tags: python, directory

I need the second newest file.

In this thread the newest is found:

[Python get most recent file in a directory with certain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134495/python-get-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-with-certain-extension)

which uses this construct:

```
newest = min(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)
```

However, how can I get not the min or max but the second element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this can be a suitable solution:

```
# for the min + 1
sorted(glob.iglob('*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)[1]

# for the newest
sorted(glob.iglob('*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)[-1]

# for the second newest ( max - 1)
sorted(glob.iglob('*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)[-2]
```

So basically `glob.iglob('*.log')` is just an array (to be more precise it result is a generator) - you can sort it by ctime and find what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
sorted_list = sorted(glob.iglob('upload/*.log'), key=os.path.getctime)
sorted_list[-2]
```