# Get second newest file in a folder

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to get most recent and second most recent file in a directory.
here is my code

```
import glob
import os

path = r'C:\temp\Processed\*'
list_of_files = glob.glob(path) # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
sorted_files = sorted(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print sorted_files[-1]
print sorted_files[-2]
```

Reference: [Second newest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35364558/second-newest-file)

`latest_file[-1]` returns the newest file (`170608_191655__Equity_Watched.csv`), but `latest_file[-2]` gives me a `170607_082445__Equity_Watched.csv` which is not the second most recent. I was expecting to get `170607_231353__Equity_Watched.csv`.

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `latest_file` is an undefined variable.  Also, please post what you get when you `print sorted_files`.

Comment: my bad. Correcting it now

Comment: all good. I should have used getmtime. My issue is resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you actually want `getmtime`, not `getctime` (since you're showing us a screenshot showing **modification** times).

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted_files = sorted(list_of_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
print sorted_files[-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, here are a couple ways to possible go about it.

1. Reverse the sort.  Sort it in the other direction and try accessing `sorted_list[0]` and `sorted_list[1]`.  Maybe that will give you a more promising result
2. Access file in the list and sort yourself. You could loop through the list, run `os.path.getctime` on them, and use that data to find the recent and second most recent items yourself.
3. Continue to google or wait on another answer. Or use getmtime as Stefan mentioned...

Best of luck!