# Display image on the panel on button click

Tags: image, python-2.7, button, onclick, wxpython

Using the script below, a panel with a button will display. Every time I'm going to click the display button I want an image to display also on the panel. How will I do that?

Below are code snippets but unfortunately the display function is blank because I don't have any idea what to add to that function:

```
    def InitUI(self):   

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        disbtn = wx.Button(pnl, label='Display', pos=(30, 150))

        cbtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDis)

        self.SetSize((500, 400))
        self.SetTitle('wx.Button')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)          

    def OnDis(self, e):
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wx.StaticBitmap` to display your image. But to grab your image file, I would recommend using Python's `glob` module to get a list of images and then use the `os` module to determine which image file is the newest.

Here's some more information on the glob module:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

For getting the newest file, I would use this StackOverflow example and edit it for your file's extension:

- [Python: Find newest file with .MP3 extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279063/python-find-newest-file-with-mp3-extension-in-directory)

As for learning about displaying images in wxPython, I would recommend downloading wxPython's demo package. It has some great examples. You can also check out this tutorial:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/

Comment: I have tried to run the glob module and this error appears `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'iglob'`. Am using python 2.7.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. According to the documentation, it's been there since Python 2.5 - https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: Tried to run this `import os`
`import glob`
`newest = max(glob.iglob('*.[Mm][Pp]3'), key=os.path.getctime)`
`print newest` and the result was `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`. Do I need to specify a directory for the path?

Comment: I think so. Even a `./` would work. There are several examples in the previously linked documentation.

Comment: How will I bind the glob and wx to come up with the idea that every day the view button will be click, the newest image from a directory will also appear instead of that just printing the newest files?

Comment: Did you look at the second link? You can use the details there to tell iglob to return the newest path only.

Comment: Yes I have looked at it and tried it. And it prints the newest file from the path I had specified. But I mean the gui itself. How will I make the 'view' button display 'that newest file/image'  inside the frame/within the panel(beside the button). I hope I'm explaining it well.

Comment: In your button's event handler, you would call `glob.iglob` to get the path to the newest file. Then you would put the image in a `wx.Image` widget (i.e. `img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)`) and then call your `wx.StaticBitmap`'s `SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))` method. That last tutorial explains how to display images, you just have to add the glob magic.

Comment: I don't know if wxPython supports displaying tiffs

Comment: The pixel size of my sample image is 2400X2065 and it's too big to display in the panel. What should I do to view the whole image without affecting the quality of the image? Just want to set the size smaller to fit into the panel with a scrollbar(e.g. 1000x860), or maybe the best option is to allow the image to zoom in and out. Would that be possible?

Comment: You would probably need to scale it down to fit your screen. The tutorial I linked to explains how to scale images down. For zooming, you might want to look at the FloatPanel.

Comment: Tried to search for floatpanel but can't find any that involves zooming image inside a panel/frame using it.

Comment: Oops...I meant FloatCanvas - http://wiki.wxpython.org/FloatCanvas or see the docs - http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.floatcanvas.FloatCanvas.html#module-lib.floatcanvas.FloatCanvas

Comment: By the way, how will I also print the name of the image that was displayed in the panel?I was able to display the image(using glob) but also want to print its file name. I just want to know, if I have a directory which has a new file everyday, and if I'm using the glob module does that mean it will also update or display the newest file in every day?

Comment: glob will run against whatever's in the directory. It doesn't keep a cache

Comment: What about when I click a button, and the newest image that the glob module retrieves will be copied to another folder/directory, will  that be possible?

Comment: glob does not copy files, so no, that is not possible. If you want to copy / move files, you will want to take a look at the shutil module. Also, if you have additional questions, you should submit them to Stack instead of adding new comments.