# How to print latest file that starts with using python?

Tags: python, file, glob

Is it possible to print the newest file using `startswith`? example: startswith "DOG"

```
import subprocess
import os
import glob

list_of_files = glob.iglob("C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\*")
latest_file = 
print latest_file
```

Comment: Last created, or last modified?

Comment: Directories included, or only files? What about shortcuts?

Comment: Only if the file name startswith some datetime string and you know exactly which string you're looking for.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=stat#os.stat may help.

Comment: @roganjosh: No, most popular filesystems store "meta-data" as well, like the creation time, editing time, and last opened timestamp.

Comment: Take a look at [Python: Find newest file with .MP3 extension in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18279063/953482). It's effectively asking "how do I find the latest file that _ends with_ something?", but you should be able to convert the existing answers to use startswith instead.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I interpreted as the specific string method `startswith()` in which case I think the circumstances that I described would be the only way of doing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know what do you mean by `startswith`, but try this:

```
files = glob.iglob(r"C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner\*")
latest_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

Comment: this worked thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Making a system call such as `os.path.getctime` on every file in a directory can be slow and expensive. It's many times more efficient to use `os.scandir` to obtain all the information of files in a directory in one call since it is readily available during the call to obtain a directory listing.

```
import os
directory = r"C:\Users\Guest\Desktop\OJT\scanner"
latest_file = max(os.scandir(directory), key=lambda f: f.stat().ST_MTIME).name
```

Please read [PEP-471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) for details.